# VS-Code unable to catch firebase auth exception (Flutter)

Tags: visual-studio, exception, flutter, firebase-authentication

Using VS-Code for my Flutter App,
Signing-in users by SMS code.

Trying to catch google auth expectation **which works fine on Android Studio** but not on VS-Code (When SMS code is wrong).

this is what I used:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).catchError((e) {
      print("Wrong SMSCode");
    }).then((user) {
      print(user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser);
    });
```

Any suggestions on how to make it work on VS-Code?

Comment: I don't think there is any flutter/dart code which works fine on one IDE successfully and on the other it doesn't.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad thank you. Probably best doing it native